# Turning data long to wide with repeating values

Tags: r, reshape2

```
  fill       W   id       X        T
    1       403 29730    100      111
    1      8395 10766    100       92
    1      4170 14291    100       98
    1      2768 20506    200      110
    1      3581 15603    100      112
    6         1 10504    200       87
    9       48  29730    100       89
    1     4790  10766    200       80
```

This is a slightly modified random sample from my actual data. I'd like:

```
 id       X        T   403 8395 ....
 29730    100      111   1
 10766    100       92       1  
 14291    100       98
 20506    200      110
 15603    100      112
 10504    200       87
 29730    100       89
 10766    200       80
```

Notice ID `29730` is both in T `89` and `111`. I think this should just be `reshape2::dcast` however

`data_wide <- reshape2::dcast(data_long, id + T + X  ~ W, value.var = "fill")` gives an illogical result. Is there generally a to keep the same ID at T1 and T2 while casting a data frame?

Comment: Isn't this just a reshaping problem? `tidyr::spread(df, W, fill)` Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is *not* a trivial *reshape long to wide* question considering OP's requirements:

1. The row order must be maintained.
2. The columns must be ordered in appearance of `W`.
3. Missing entries should appear blank rather than `NA`.

This requires

- to add a row number to be included in the reshape formula,
- to turn `W` into a factor where the factor levels are ordered by appearance using `forecats::fct_inorder()`, e.g.,
- to use a aggregation function which turns `NA` in `""` using `toString()`, e.g.,
- and to remove the row numbers from the reshaped result.

Here, the `data.table` implementation of `dcast()` is used as `data.table` appears a bit more convenient, IMHO.

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(data_long)[, rn := .I], rn + id + T + X  ~ forcats::fct_inorder(factor(W)), 
      toString, value.var = "fill")[
        , rn := NULL][]
```

> ```
>       id   T   X 403 8395 4170 2768 3581 1 48 4790
> 1: 29730 111 100   1                              
> 2: 10766  92 100        1                         
> 3: 14291  98 100             1                    
> 4: 20506 110 200                  1               
> 5: 15603 112 100                       1          
> 6: 10504  87 200                         6        
> 7: 29730  89 100                            9     
> 8: 10766  80 200                                 1
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
data_long <- fread("  fill       W   id       X        T
    1       403 29730    100      111
    1      8395 10766    100       92
    1      4170 14291    100       98
    1      2768 20506    200      110
    1      3581 15603    100      112
    6         1 10504    200       87
    9       48  29730    100       89
    1     4790  10766    200       80")
```